# How do I deal with specific elements only in an array?

Tags: arrays, addition, element

So I know how to add up all the elements of an array using a for loop. But how would I go about adding up only the positive elements?

Say my array included `{3, -9, 2, -10}`

I want to: `3 + 2 (giving 5)`
NOT: `3 +-9 +2 +-10 (giving -14)`

Also how would I get the amount of positive elements in an array? (i.e. in this example there are two positive elements)

Im using Java/Eclipse

Thanks so much for the answers - i now know what to do! This is my first time here - do i have to mark this as answered or something?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: By not adding the negative ones: you will need a conditional (`if` in most languages). To count something, add a local integer initialised to zero, and increment it, in the loop, each time you detect the thing you are looking for. Think about what you would do if you where doing it, instead of the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a condition in your loop :

```
arrays = {3, -9, 2, -10};

sum = 0;
nb_elem = 0;
for (i = 0 ; i < arrays.length ; i++)
{
    if (arrays[i] > 0)
    {
        sum += arrays[i];
        nb_elem++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: When I posted this message you had not said what language you want this. I have written a generic code, an algorithm. Do you need help to convert in Java?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you are using, so I'll give you example in Python

```
def sum_up_positive_values(array):
    result = 0
    for value in array:
        if value > 0:
            result += value
    return result
```